# Outlook 2010 - Rule to move everything that would otherwise go to Inbox only

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

My issue is that I have a work iphone on which I need important notifications for certain emails (which can be distinguished with a 'subject contains' rule), but iOS only allows selective notifications for emails from 'VIP' addresses (no good here since I will have unimportant emails coming from the same addresses), or for particular subfolders (ideal, except you can't turn off notifications for the main inbox).

The workaround that I think might do the trick is to have an outlook rule which moves any emails which would normally end up in the Inbox into another folder (call it myInbox). Then I can have iphone notifications turned on for my important folder and off for the myInbox folder, and since no emails will be in my actual Inbox I won't get any notifications from that.

Is there a way to make such a rule? I have tried having a simple rule which matches everything and moves it at the end of my rules, but some of my existing rules can't specify 'Stop processing rules' since they are client only, so they also end up getting copied over to myInbox.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two workarounds here:

- Create catch-all rule that moves everything to myInbox and specify required exceptions for this rule. This allows to transfer the message to other rules. Move this rule to the top.
- Keep your Outlook always running, do not shutdown the computer and do not close Outlook.